# Update a data value from a method called in mounted

Tags: vue.js, methods, nuxt.js

I have this code and the goal from it is to update a data `sticky` to true if the scroll position is > than 0

```
export default {
  components: {
  },
  data() {
    return {
      menuVisible: false,
      sticky: false,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.checkScroll()
  },
  methods: {
    checkScroll() {
      document.querySelector('body').onscroll = function() {
        console.log(window.pageYOffset > 0)
        this.sticky = window.pageYOffset > 0
      }
    },
  },
}
```

the problem is that even that i see the true console logged, the data is allways false ( as the initial value )

[image]
[image]

Any idea why is not updating it?

Comment: Try an arrow function instead:  `.onscroll = () => {`

Comment: you could put the jquery outside of the vue code and just make this.sticky a global var

Comment: @hurnhu there is no jQuery here, and making `sticky` a global variable is not the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because of the callback you're passing into your scroll listener. In your callback `this` is not the context of the vue component. I think its the body actually. You'll need to use an arrow function or pass the vue instance into the callback as an argument. Arrow function is easiest. An arrow function retains the context where it was defined rather than inheriting the context of the object that calls it. Here is a good post/answer about the [difference between normal and arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361380/2687861).

```
document.querySelector('body').onscroll = () => {
    console.log(window.pageYOffset > 0)
    this.sticky = window.pageYOffset > 0
}
```